# WPF Datagrid edit cell issue

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

When I bind my `ObservableCollection` to my `DataGrid` with `AutoGenerateColumns` to true. I can double click on the cell I want to edit and then I can edit the text that is in the cell.

But when I set `AutoGenerateColumns` to false and want to use custom `DataGridTextColumns`, I can also double click the cell. But the text that was in there is removed so I have an empty string instead of the one I wanted to edit a little bit.

Any ideas on this issue?

This is my `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" 
          Margin="0,10,30,0" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle}"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6,0,0,0" />
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Description}" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Edit:**
I also noticed that when `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to false and when I insert a new row the binded text isn't getting set...
And when I set `AutoGeneratedColumns` to true it binds the inserted text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The data grid had a datagrid template column and that column has a CellTemplate and a CellEditingTemplate.  If you define the template for both you can explicitly set the binding for both as well.  Maybe that will solve your problem.

here is sample of template column with both templates

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="TEXT" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourBindingProperty}" Style="{StaticResource YourEditStyle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox x:Name="EditTextbox" Text="{Binding YourBindingProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Style="{StaticResource YourEditStyle}">
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Hope this helps